# How to implement reCaptcha with firebase in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, angularfire2

I am trying to implement recaptcha with firebase in angular, but getting the error below.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined

In the .ts file I am trying the following:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

recaptchaVerifier: firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;

constructor(private windowService: WindowService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.windowRef = this.windowService.windowRef;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      size: 'normal',
      callback: (response) => {
             ...
         }
      });
      this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
      this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();
}
```

windowService

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WindowService {

   get windowRef() {
       return window;
   }
}
```

in the template:

```
<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for any response!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import everything from firebase, currently .auth is not included.
try this:

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`
instead of
`import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried it already, in this case in VSCode `auth` is underlined in `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container')` and the app is not complying.. How to import `auth` and `RecaptchaVerifier` then?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I downgraded angular/fire and firebase to:

```
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
"firebase": "^7.14.0",
```

In this case the import `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` works,  and I was able to use `RecaptchaVerifier` like:

```
recaptchaVerifier: firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;

ngOnInit() {
   this.windowRef = this.windowService.windowRef;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   let captchaElement = document.getElementById('recaptcha-container');
   if (captchaElement != null) {
      this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container',    
         {
            size: 'normal',
            callback: (response) => {
               this.disableSignUpBtn = false;
            }
         });
         this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
         this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();
      }
 }
```